# Why ExpressionEngine?

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager, ecommerce, multi-language

I need multiple-domain support, some e-commerce catalog, uploading files from users and some forum feauteres in future. Is it good choice for this tasks?
Why not Drupal, or Modx, or wordpress - for free?
Any ExpressionEngine advantages?
Thanks

Comment: I've closed your question because it's too broad and open-ended. Please feel free to post more specific questions which meet our FAQ guidelines: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need multiple-domain support, some e-commerce catalog, uploading
>   files from users and some forum feauteres in future. Is it good choice
>   for this tasks?

Yes, ExpressionEngine can do all those tasks, although for multi-domain support you will probably need the [Multiple Site Manager](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/index.html) (available for [purchase](https://store.ellislab.com/) separately) , and for the ecommerce you will probably need third party software. [Here](http://cartthrob.com/site/compare) are [a few](https://exp-resso.com/store/comparison) options you can [compare](http://www.brilliantretail.com).

> Why not Drupal, or Modx, or wordpress - for free? Any ExpressionEngine
>   advantages?

Use whatever tool best fits the job. I usually choose ExpressionEngine because:

- **It has a great combination of power and flexibility.** You can build
  almost anything with it, by defining you own custom fields. It makes
  no assumptions about the architecture of your site. It fits in around
  your needs, not the other way round.
- I am primarily a content creator, graphic designer and front-end dev.
  I'm not a heavy-duty programmer. **ExpressionEngine's template tag
  syntax is easy to learn and understand** ([example](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html)).
- Anything that ExpressionEngine can't do out-of-the-box, can be done with **add-ons, of which there are many** (both free and paid). Check out http://devot-ee.com/
- **The ExpressionEngine community** are a fantastic, active, and helpful bunch. Because it's a commercial product, **it's supported**, so anything the community can't help you with, [EllisLab can](http://ellislab.com/support).